# Powering 3 HDD's with external power

Tags: raspbian, usb, power, hard-drive

I'm trying to connect 3 HDD's to my Pi3.

They are 2x 3.5" and 1x 2.5", all powered with a external power supply: https://www.inateck.com/inateck-ua1001-usb-3-0-to-ide-sata-adapter.html

It works if I only connect one drive, but as soon as I add a second one they stop working.
They are all 1TB and perfectly work on my windows machine or if I disconnect the other ones.

Is there a way to tell the Pi not to power the Drives throught the USB?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you doing hot swapping and plugging in and out of the USB with the Pi already booted and running? This post may provide some information about that topic https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=23205

Comment: See also this posting https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/65995/how-can-i-control-power-to-a-usb-powered-device

Comment: Another possibility is to use a USB cable that has the power leads in the cable cut so that it is data only. This article talks about doing so for a powered hub power back feed issue http://www.whatimade.today/how-to-protect-a-rasperry-pi-from-a-powered-usb-hub/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the Pi 4 power 2 external USB 3 HDDs?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104038/can-the-pi-4-power-2-external-usb-3-hdds)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Y-type USB cable

[image: foo]

Power one male jack from a 3A power supply, another goes into the Pi. Expect 1-1.5A per drive to operate without problems. If you can’t readily or cheaply get such a high current supply for 5V, get a nice buck converter and use it with a laptop power brick.